# Service fabric tooling in VS2017 seems to be broken

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have updated service fabric core SDK to 2.5.216 (released March 21st)and also installed Visual Studio 2017. When I open my sf projects in VS2017 it starts showing this message.
[image]

I guess this maybe because VS2017 SF tools weren't updated to latest version? I also see that there is no update on thatyet in the new VS2017 installer. Can anyone help me out to figure this issue?

**Update:**

Looks like the [release notes](https://servicefabricsdkstorage.blob.core.windows.net/public-release-notes/Microsoft%20Azure%20Service%20Fabric%20Release%20Notes%20-%20SDK%202.5.216%20-%20Runtime%205.5.216.docx) already explains that next version of VS2017 update will include 1.5 version of SF tools. Do you have an estimated timeline on when that update could be released?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve that?

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor VS2017 got a latest update today. Once you update it, it should be fine. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately right now the tooling in VS 2017 is still 1.4. In the *.sfproj* file there are references to the MSBuild package - which were not updated.

Try to delete the packages folder and reinstall MSBuild package for service fabric project

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild
```

Comment: Make sure you keep on using the same version of the NuGet package as the tooling version (specified in the .sfproj file).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the new tooling for VS2017, by installing Visual Studio 2017 preview https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/. The preview can run side by side with other instances of Visual Studio 2017 and contains updates to other parts of Visual Studio. For Service Fabric tooling, we do not support round tripping between Service Fabric tooling in VS2017 preview and VS2017.

We are working on being able to get updated Service Fabric tooling that you can install in to non-preview versions of Visual Studio 2017 going forward.

Answer (score 0):

VS2017 as of today April 05, 2017 released an update which fixed this issue.

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question. The answer to your question is that your sfproj file was referencing a version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild` which wasn't installed.